# MYSQL Match Entries that Meet Multiple Criteria over Multiple Rows

Tags: php, mysql

I think this will be an easy one for those using MYSQL a lot, but I just can't quite get it...mainly through not knowing the right terminology to search for.

Basically I have a table mapping tag ids to photo ids called tag_map. When I perform this query:

```
SELECT * FROM tag_map WHERE tag_id='1' OR tag_id='5';
```

I get the following results:

```
ph_id   tag_id
1       1
2       1
5       1
7       5
8       1
9       5
10      5
11      1
12      1
13      1
```

But what I really want is to only select ph_id that have a tag_id of BOTH '1' and '5'.

So, as you can probably see, I am trying to filter down selections based on multiple tags. I want to end up with:

```
ph_id   tag_id
7       1
7       5
8       1
8       5
11      1
11      5
```

So ph_id 7, 8 and 11 reference tag_id 1 AND 5.

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks.

## Solution

Due to the dynamic nature of my query (user selecting any number of available tags to 'narrow down selection) I went with a PHP solution, as suggested by @Y U NO WORK

Basically I get the tag_id of all selected tags from table 'tags'

Then I selected all photo ids (ph_id) that are mapped to the selected tag_ids from my table tag_map.

Then I reduce this down to ph_ids that occur the same number of times as the number of selected tags:

```
$numTags = count($arTagId); //$arTagId is an array of the selected tags

// get only photo ids that match both tags
$arPhId = array();
// in arPhId, find ph_ids that have occurances equal to $numTags
$arPhIdCnt = array_count_values($arPhIdAll); //$arPhIdAll is array of all ph_id that match all selected tag_ids

foreach($arPhIdCnt as $pid => $pidQty) {
  if($pidQty == $numTags) {
    $arPhId[] = $pid;
  }
}
```

So I end up with an array of only the ph_ids that match both tag_ids.

Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to join the table with itself, the code could be kinda complicated. PHP would be an easier, but not such a performant solution.

Comment: Am starting to wonder if PHP might be the route...I am using PHP to build the query anyway.

Comment: PHP is easier for sure, but will be less performant for your webserver. You just save all the ph_ids with their tag_ids. Then you use "array_count_values($ph_id)" and only save those where the value of this function is higher than 1.

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the table with itself based on ph_id, then check that the tab_id col of table1 instance equals 1 and that tab_id of table2 instance equals 5.

```
SELECT t1.* FROM tag_map t1, tag_map t2
WHERE t1.ph_id = t2.ph_id
AND t1.tag_id='1' 
AND t2.tag_id='5';
```

with inner join if you prefer

```
SELECT t1.* FROM tag_map t1
INNER JOIN tag_map t2 on t2.ph_id=t1.ph_id
WHERE t1.tag_id='1' 
AND t2.tag_id='5';
```

Comment: This is great and so simple...but what if I have 3 tag_ids? Or 4... is it just `SELECT t1.* FROM tag_map t1, tag_map t2, tag_map t3
WHERE t1.ph_id = t2.ph_id (WHAT GOES HERE?)
AND t1.tag_id='1' 
AND t2.tag_id='5'
AND t3.tag_id='n';`

Comment: @j0nr in that case you could approach it as so SELECT t1.* FROM tag_map t1, tag_map t2, tag_map t3 WHERE t1.ph_id = t2.ph_id and t2.ph_id=t3.ph_id AND t1.tag_id='1' AND t2.tag_id='5' AND t3.tag_id='n';